# Connect to MS Exchange Server using javascript/NodeJS

Tags: node.js, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

Does anyone know if any example of how to connect to MS Exchange server and pull out a users calendar & tasks (using javascript or otherwise)

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if it's not a SOAP 1.2 service (ie you won't be able to connect with wshttpbinding and soap 1.2)

Answer (score 0):

have you looked at [ews-javascript-api](https://github.com/gautamsi/ews-javascript-api).

disclaimer: I am author of the lib

if you can post more specific requirement, I will be able to answer. some of the examples ae already in GitHub issues to search